# Issue displaying all reports for a given project with handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am creating a website that keeps track of projects and reports. My goal is to create a front end endpoint (http://localhost:3001/post/1) that shows all of the reports that are associated for a given project. The source code can be found here: https://github.com/CullerWhale/projectTracker

The website uses sequelize, mysql2, and express for handlebars and sessions. One user can have many projects, and one project can have many reports. All reports belong to one project and all projects belong to one user.

**FYI: projects are referred to as posts in the code, I will fix this at the end, I just want to keep moving forward.**

I was able to correctly display all reports for a given logged in user:

[image]

I used the dashboard.handlebars file to do this. It also consisted of utilizing the post-info.handlebars partial file as well as the post-routes.js file.

I then created a new model: Reports. I added the associates in the index.js file of the routes/api directory. I reloaded the table and created a new partial for reports: report-info.handlebars

I did the same process for creating the dashboard to display all reports for one user. However, its not displaying the reports for a given project:

[image]

Here is the code for the single-post.handlebars page:

```
{{> post-info post }}

{{#if loggedIn}}
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Edit project</button>
    <button type="button" class="upvote-btn">Delete project</button>
  </div>
{{/if}}

{{#if post.reports.length}}
<section>
  <h2>Reports for this post</h2>
  <ol>
    {{#each post.reports as |report|}}
    <li>
      <div class="report-content">
        {{> report-info report}}
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="edit-link-container">
        <a href="/dashboard/edit/{{report.id}}" class="edit-link">Edit report</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ol>
  {{else}}
  <p>No reports found for this post.</p>
</section>
{{/if}}



<section>
  <h2>Create New Report</h2>

  <form class="new-post-form">
    <div>
      <label for="post-title">Report Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="post-title" name="post-title" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="post-url">Previous report</label>
      <input id="post-url" name="post-url" />
    </div>
    {{!-- {{#if loggedIn}} --}}
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Generate new report</button>
      {{!-- <button type="button" class="upvote-btn">Create new report</button> --}}
    </div>
  </form>
  {{!-- {{/if}} --}}
</section>



<script src="/javascript/add-post.js"></script>
```

Here are the partial files...
post-info.handlebars:

```
<article class="post">
<div class="title">
    <a href="/post/{{id}}">{{title}}</a>
    <span>({{post_url}})</span>
</div>
<div class="meta">
    by {{user.username}} on
    {{created_at}}
    <a href="/post/{{id}}"></a>
</div>
```

report-info.handlebars:

```
<article class="report">
<div class="title">
    <a href="{{post.post_url}}" target="_blank">{{title}}</a>
</div>
<div class="post-url">
    <span>{{post.post_url}}</span>
</div>
<div class="meta">
    <span>by {{user.username}}</span>
</div>
```

I created seed data. The reports exist and they are associated with projects:
[image]

I have tried a myriad of things and I just cant get it to work. Any help is immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after sleeping on it. I was focused on the post-routes.js file and using multiple partials. However, I should have focused on the report-routes.js file, the appropriate location to add a query to find all reports for a given post.